# Element following user message

Tags: javascript, python, html

I have created a unique web chat using websockets and python for the server. It's very basic at the moment however there's a feature I'd like to implement but I'm not sure as to how I'd go about it.

I made a div which is basically a small red square which is located beside the chat input, when a user types a message and clicks enter/submit I'd like for that red square to be at the end of the message which is displayed in the chat log.

The only clue I can think of is that it would involve an appendTo in js after an event has occured (the sending of the message) using a listener but I'm unsure as to how it would detect the end of a message. Any ideas? Hopefully it's a possible task.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="send">
<div id="box"></div>

<!-- Message appears here -->

<fieldset id="chatlog"></fieldset>
```

**CSS**

```
div#box {
    background:url(http://i.imgur.com/iJipdb6.png) no-repeat;
    width: 10px;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 9px;
    left: 110px;
```

**SERVER**

```
var messages;
            var form;
            var inputBox;

            function log_msg(msg) {
                var p = document.createElement("p");
                p.innerHTML = msg;
                messages.appendChild(p);
            }

            function doInit() {
                inputBox = document.getElementById("message");
                messages = document.getElementById("messages");
                form = document.getElementById("message-form");
                var s;
                try {
                    var host = "ws://localhost:4545/";
                    if(window.location.hostname) {
                        host = "ws://" + window.location.hostname + ":4545/";
                    }

                    s = new WebSocket(host);

                    s.onopen = function (e) { log_msg("connected..."); };
                    s.onclose = function (e) { log_msg("connection closed."); };
                    s.onerror = function (e) { log_msg("connection error."); };
                    s.onmessage = function (e) { log_msg("message: " + e.data); };
                } catch (ex) {
                    log_msg("connection exception:" + ex);
                }

                form.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    s.send(inputBox.value);
                    inputBox.value = "";
                }, false);
            }
```

**IMAGE for further clarification:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EMgM.png

Comment: I don't really get it... Do you have a screenshot maybe ? You want this box DIV to be appended to the text _inside_ the textarea ? or _after_ the textarea ?

Comment: I'd to append it inside the textarea after the message: http://i.imgur.com/RkBpAMI.png

Comment: Well then it's not gonna be easy my friend, I'll try to think of something. Thanks for the image, it's much easier to understant now

Answer (score 0):

beTo my knowledge, it is not possible. A *textarea* only accepts raw text. To be able to do that, you will need to format your chat log in HTML.

On the top of my head and just for the sake of scratching it a little, you could imagine calculating the grid of your textarea (chars on *x* axis * chars on *y* axis), then calculate where on this grid the square would end up based on the length of its value, and absolutely position the box to simulate it being in the textarea. It could manageable since textarea are by default in monospace fonts, but this is a very bad idea. I would just make it HTML, it will be easier.

Comment: I've managed to change the textarea into a fieldset and put the box in there just to see if it displays and surprisingly it worked! But I'm still unsure on how to send it after a message on enter.

Comment: Yes it should work as long as the textarea is inside an element that is `position: relative`, now you can use my idea to calculate where it should be displayed depending on the length of the string inside the textarea. Again, I strongly advise that you do this for fun and do not use this technique in production.